# How to change colors for ListView, alternating row color?

Tags: android, listview, colors, selection

I have a couple of list views, one uses TextViews laid out with xml, the other uses a custom class derived from View.  The default halloween color scheme is pretty ugly.  How can I change the background and selection colors for the list elements.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this in code not xml, to handle the custom view.

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change the background and
>   selection colors for the list
>   elements.

`android:background` for the background of your row `Views`, `android:listSelector` for the `ListView` list selector.